# select2 plugin not giving any change

Tags: select, combobox, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I'm working on a web app with laravel5 and bootstrap3and I tried to use  [select2](http://select2.github.io/)   to make autocomplete comboboxes but it's giving me no result and the comboboxes are still the same.

I have downloaded select 2 files from github and put dist directory in public directory of my project and also included the links of the css and js files like this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('/select2/css/select2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('/select2/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
```

/select2 is actually the dist directory, I renamed it.

I have a combobox like this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="resp">
   <option value="">Select one...</option>
   <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
   <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
   <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
   <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

and I call the select2 script this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#resp').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you're right I've been loading the select2 script before JQuery, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because of one of two issues

- You are not including jQuery *before* Select2.
- You are trying to initialize Select2 before the JavaScript has been loaded.

Comment: Yes I was not including jQuery before select2, thank you Kevin Brown